# will this cronjob work?

Tags: php, cron

im trying to set up a cronjob to run a PHP file. i just want to know if i am doing it right or not.

lets say the php is located at http://mysite.com/myscript/cronjob.php, and i want it to run every 3 hours.

i am very new to cronjobs so i apologise if it seems like i have no clue what i am doing.

```
Minute  Hour    Day     Month   Weekday     Command

*   */3     *   *   *   http://mysite.com/myscript/cronjob.php
```

i want this to run that PHP script every 3 hours. will this work or do i have to use a different command?

Comment: You need to use commands your system understands. And there are many good crontab howtos online. Google until you find one that speaks your language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this won't work.  A URL is not an executable, it is simply a URL.

You could put `wget http://mysite.com/myscript/cronjob.php` for your command, but is that really what you want?

The best way (if the script is on the local server) is to call PHP directly:

`php /var/www/myscript/cronjob.php`

Answer (score 4):

Almost, this should do it

```
* */3 * * * wget -q -o /dev/null http://mysite.com/myscript/cronjob.php
```

or with curl

```
* */3 * * * curl -s -o /dev/null http://mysite.com/myscript/cronjob.php
```

the -s / -q will silent the output and the -o will redirect the scripts output into /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said about not being able to specify a URL to query:

I've found several references online [that](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/372336) [warn](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

> A. ) Repeat pattern like /2 for every 2 minutes or /10 for every 10 minutes is not supported by all operating systems. If you try to use it and crontab complains it is probably not supported.

However assuming repeat patterns are supported, it should work.

So a more portable way would be to do:

```
*   0,3,9,12,15,18,21     *   *   *   php /var/www/myscript/cronjob.php
```

Comment: Your cron fetches URLs for you?

Comment: @Brad err no, it doesn't. Didn't see that :)