# How do I write a script to make an API request and store it on my server every day?

Tags: php, api, scripting

Sorry if this is basic, I haven't ever had to do something like this before.

I'm building a website that makes API calls to services (such as Soundcloud), and the calls can sometimes take a while (5-10 seconds). Rather than make these calls every time a user loads the page, I want to make the call once a day, store the result on my server, and just call *that* every time a user loads the page. The data shouldn't change very often during one day anyways.

My question is how can I do this? I am familiar with PHP, which I believe is good for this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to be more specific in what you are wanting to do. Try and do it, then show us any code you are having problems with.

Comment: You'll write a PHP script that does the call and stores the result in a file, and then you'll set up a cron job on the server that runs that script once a day. In your application/website you'll just get the stored file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set it up as a cron job that runs however often you need (assuming it's a Linux server). You could see how to do it, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720451/will-this-cronjob-work). A lot of shared hosting providers also allow setting cron jobs in their control panel interface.

However, if you cannot set up a cron job, what's preventing you from storing the result from the API request on your server once and then using the stored data later, instead of calling the API again?

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize, there are a couple of ways to do what you want to do. One would be to set up a cron job that runs the script like adeneo said. Another solution might be to store a timestamp somewhere, and then check that timestamp when the page is hit and decide whether or not to update. That way, you can ensure that the script is only run on the first hit of the day, or something like that.